# Breeze.WebApi2 Authentication Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

Tags: breeze

Now that AS.NET WebApi2 has an integrated authorization mechanism using tokens.
How can we integrate this mechanism with Breeze.WebApi2. That is Breeze.WebApi2 and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.

What I need is how to modify the project created using visual studio 2013 project wizard that is configured to use individual accounts in security into a breeze web api 2 server with the same security setup.

I tried it by creating a web api project with individual accounts security and then added breeze web api 2 server using nuget package but that was s bit confusing to me.
A sample code or application would be more useful for me to get started.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the **Authorize** attribute you can also access the user data via the "User" variable.

```
[BreezeController]
[Authorize]
public class NorthwindIBModelController : ApiController {

   [HttpGet]
   public IQueryable<Customer> CustomerList() {
     var userName = User.Identity.Name;

     var filter = filter on customers;
     var custs = ContextProvider.Context.Customers.Where({ some filter using userName});
   }

}
```

Comment: I have added more elaboration in my earlier question please view it.